# Calculating Variance of Monte Carlo Estimate

Tags: matlab, montecarlo

I want to estimate the variance of R_LW, this is the ratio of the mean square error (MSE) of the estimator LW to the standard OLS estimator (R stands for ratio).

Each MSE is calculated over 5000 sims to give one R_LW.  I want to know what the standard deviation of the estimate of Ratio R_LW is.

To estimate this I repeat the process 100 times to gain 100 estimates of R_LW and then calculate the variance of the 100 R_LWs produced. What I am seeing is that the R_LWs produced consecutively in the 100 simulations tend to be very similar in value resulting in a low overall variance 3.81E-06.

However when I rerun the whole process the it produces another 100 estimates of R_LW which although close to each other and producing a similar variance to the first set, the average value that they fluctuate around tends to have moved a lot further than the estimated variance of either run would suggest.

Given a variance of 3.8106 this equates to a standard deviation of 0.001953 so I would not expect to see a movement of more than 3 standard deviations over 100 sims, and indeed within one simulation run you don't see a movement larger than that across the 100 samples.

However when you look at the R_LW's between different runs it's mean value moves around a lot! See below

Run1  0.6133
Run2  0.5901
Run3  0.6169
Run4  0.5833
Run5  0.6161
Stdev 0.016

The between runs standard deviation is nearly 10 times higher? I'm guessing it had to do with how normrnd() is seeded?

```
 clear;
 tic
dim=1;
flag=0;
n=30;
p1=3;
p2=2;
alpha1=0.9;
alpha2=0.9;
error_vol=1^0.5;

MSE_OLS=0;
MSE_R=0;

MSE_OLS_tot=0;
MSE_LW_tot=0;
MSE_OLS_AVR=0;
MSE_R_AVR=0;
SUM_STD_MSE_OLS=0;
SUM_STD_MSE_R=0;
STD_OLS=0;
STD_R=0;

nsims=5000;
tot_p=p1+p2;
x=zeros(n,tot_p);

for i=1:n
 z_i4=normrnd(0,1);
 for j=1:p1     
     x(i,j)=x(i,j)+alpha1*z_i4;
     x(i,j)= x(i,j)+(1-alpha1^2)^(0.5)*normrnd(0,1);
   end

 for j=1+p1:tot_p        
     x(i,j)=x(i,j)+alpha2*z_i4;
     x(i,j)= x(i,j)+(1-alpha2^2)^(0.5)*normrnd(0,1);
 end
end

mu= mean(x,dim);
sigma = std(x,flag,dim);
sigma0 = sigma;
sigma0(sigma0==0) = 1;
x_scaled = bsxfun(@minus,x, mu);
sigma0=sigma0*sqrt(n-1);
x_scaled = bsxfun(@rdivide, x_scaled, sigma0);

econFlag=0;
[U,sigma,coeff] = svd(x_scaled,econFlag);
b_act=coeff(:,1);

sigmax = std(x,flag,dim);
mu_x=mean(x,dim);
nrepl=100;

R_LW_tot=0;
R_LW_sq=0;
R_LW_var=0;

for vv=1:nrepl

for t=1:nsims

residuals=normrnd(0,error_vol,n,1);


y=x*b_act + residuals;

mu_y=mean(y,dim);
mu_y=mu_y*ones(n,1);
sigmay = std(y,flag,dim);

mu= mean(y,dim);
sigma = std(y,flag,dim);
sigma0 = sigma;
sigma0(sigma0==0) = 1;
y_scaled = bsxfun(@minus,y, mu);
sigma0=sigma0*sqrt(n-1);
y_scaled = bsxfun(@rdivide, y_scaled, sigma0);

b=x_scaled\y_scaled;    
[b_LW k_LW]=LW(y_scaled, x_scaled);

for i=1:tot_p
    b_LW(i)=b_LW(i)*sigmay/sigmax(i);
end


MSE_OLS=(b-b_act)'*(b-b_act);
MSE_LW=(b_LW-b_act)'*(b_LW-b_act);

MSE_OLS_tot=MSE_OLS_tot+MSE_OLS;
MSE_LW_tot=MSE_LW_tot+MSE_LW;

end


MSE_OLS_AVR=MSE_OLS_tot/nsims;
MSE_LW_AVR=MSE_LW_tot/nsims;



R_LW=MSE_LW_AVR/MSE_OLS_AVR;    
R_LW_store(vv)=R_LW;
R_LW_tot=R_LW_tot+R_LW;
R_LW_sq=R_LW_sq+R_LW^2;
end

R_LW_var=(R_LW_sq)-(R_LW_tot^2/nrepl)/(nrepl-1);

toc
```

LW:

```
function [b k]=LW(y,x)

[n, p]=size(x);

dim=1;
flag=0;

b=x\y;

y_hat=x*b;
r=(y-y_hat);
s_squared=(r'*r)/(n-p-1);%s_squared=(r'*r)/(n-p-1);

econFlag=0;
[U,sigma,coeff] = svd(x,econFlag);%[U,sigma,coeff] = svd(z,econFlag);
EV=sigma.^2;

k=p*s_squared/(b'*x'*x*b);
pseudo = sqrt(k) * eye(p);
x_ridge  = [x;pseudo];
y_ridge  = [y;zeros(p,1)];

b = x_ridge\y_ridge;

end
```

Comment: Could you clean up your code to remove all of the extraneous spaces and random indents? Also, I'm not clear on what the code is being used to estimate – some kind of volume? And is there a known solution that you're comparing against or are you just looking at the variance? And speaking of standard deviation, [this article](http://www.edge.org/response-detail/25401) might interest you as you try to interpret your results intuitively.

Comment: Also, you might histogram your outputs (or better, use kernel density) to look at how your results are distributed.

Comment: I am trying to estimate the variance (and so standard deviation of my estimate of R_LW. I don't have a benchmark per se but comparing the results from within one run to results across runs shows something must be wrong.